# HAML - style block helpers are deprecated

Tags: haml

I have the following view that used to render without any warnings:

```
#listing
-if flash[:notice]
  .success
    =flash[:notice]
.input-container
-form_for @user do |f|
  =f.error_messages
  =render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}
```

But now when I render the view by running a functional test, I get the following warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: - style block
>   helpers are deprecated. Please use =.

Does anyone know what this warning means?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, instead of:

```
-form_for @user do |f|
```

use

```
=form_for @user do |f|
```

In other words, do exactly what it suggests.  Flip the dash into an equals.  This is new in Rails 3.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#action-view  (Section 7.4.2)

Comment: This is also new in Haml 3 too, I think.

Comment: Thanks.  I had no idea what that message was saying.  Since blocks are sometimes used in place of assigment, I thought the hyphen was just a bullet point and the message was advocating assignment instead.  Anyway, seeing an example makes it all clear.

Comment: Btw: this new syntax reflects the fact that 'form' is actually an HTML element.